# Using Spring.Net with HangFire

Tags: c#, webforms, spring.net, hangfire

We're using spring.net to manage our dependency injections but when we get to the method ran by hangfire, the dependency classes are null. Using other IoC containers are not an option yet- please dont ask why. And btw, spring.net is able to inject the dependency classes if uploadDoc() is not run through hangfire i.e. within the app's thread.

Code's like this:

```
class docUpload {
   IDependencyClass1 DClass1;
   IDependencyClass2 DClass2;

   uploadDoc() {
      DClass1.doSomething(); //Dclass1 is null here
   }
}
```

Then in spring xml:

```
<object id="docUpload " type="some code here">
    <property name="DClass1" ref="dClass1" />
    <property name="DClass2" ref="dClass2" />
</object>

<object id="dClass1" type="some code here">
<object id="dClass2" type="some code here">
```

Then hangfire executes the thread like this:

```
hangfireclass.jobclient.enqueue(() => docUpload.uploadDoc());
```

Any ideas why within a hangfire thread, spring.net's dependency injection does not work? It works if ran within the app's thread.

Comment: You need to post some real code. `docUpload` wouldn't even compile and that `xml` snippet doesn't look like valid `spring` format either.

Answer (score 0):

@ma22!

It's allowable to use Spring.NET with Hangfire.
You just should implement your JobActivator like this:

```
public class SpringNetActivator: JobActivator
{
    private readonly IApplicationContext _springContext;
    public SpringNetActivator(IApplicationContext springContext)
    {
        _springContext = springContext;
    }

    public override object ActivateJob(Type jobType)
    {
        return _springContext.GetObject(jobType.Name);
    }

    public override JobActivatorScope BeginScope(JobActivatorContext context)
    {
        //some code here
        return base.BeginScope(context);
    }
}
```

Then, you need to register it as a current job activator before starting the Hangfire server:

```
var springActivator = new SpringNetActivator(ContextRegistry.GetContext());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(springActivator);
...
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

You can read more about using IoC containers in [appropriate chapter](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html) of Hangfire documentation